# How can I make a 2-D Array in Python from a .txt file?

Tags: python, text, multidimensional-array, import

I have to import a .txt file that has 9 columns and 807022 rows into my program so I can sort through it. I have tried the code:

```
with open('ExampleTable.txt') as file:
    array2d = [[float(digit) for digit in line.split()] for line in file]
f = Find_StDev(Find12EpochStars(array2d), array2d)
print (f)
```

However, I get the error message:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '%'

The text file is floats and ints.

How can I import the .txt file so that the functions can use it?

Comment: Pretty sure the values are read as strings when reading from a file. You can use `map()` to convert them to float

Comment: are you sure that you do not have the symbol % in your file? check first. array2d = numpy.loadtxt('ExampleTable.txt') might be your friend if your file already has lines and columns.

Comment: You may see the file as containing `float`s and `int`s, but the interpreter sees a `%` symbol in one of the columns and doesn't know what to do with it because it's not a number.

Comment: Yes thank you, there was 1 '%' in the mix of 50mil numbers

Comment: If you have that amount of data, using numpy will make things a lot faster and it has nice functions to read in arrays from text files http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch out for this in the future, you can add a quick check to make sure the conversion is possible first.

For millions of numbers this shouldn't change the answer too much if one value is corrupt!

```
with open('ExampleTable.txt') as file:
    array2d = [[float(digit) for digit in line.split() if digit.isnumeric() else 0]
               for line in file]
    f = Find_StDev(Find12EpochStars(array2d), array2d)
    print (f)
```